# Append a header to the page (they are going too) when a user leaves my website

Tags: javascript, html, frames

What I am trying to accomplish is that when redirected to a external page has a frame of some sort on the page that is loaded so it would quickly allow them to come back to my site. I have tried framesets (ugly) and iframes, but some sites block the page from being loaded into the frame and I cannot get it to work properly. I am trying to figure out if it is better to load the external site in a div or what. So I am pleading for help with this issue.

Thanks!
Rob

Comment: What do you mean by "redirected"? If somebody clicks on a link on your page, and the link is to another domain, there's absolutely nothing you can do about it beyond using an "onbeforeunload" prompt.

Comment: You could construct the links to load up into a page with some contraption of frames that includes the target site, but that's a pretty broken user experience.

Comment: ... and most serious sites employ frame busters anyway.

Comment: Exactly.  If they don't, you're going to piss off the user anyhow.  That's not an expected behavior and users may avoid the site over it.

Comment: I can understand that, I was just wondering if anyone has found a way to do it. If not I will just close the ticket out. I do not want to discourage people from using the site at all. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 3):

The simplest method to use for this is to just open external links in new tabs/windows.  Some users will find this irritating, though, so be aware.  Otherwise, let people go.  They know how to use the back button, and building some some way to put the destination site into a frame and offer them a return to your site is a lot more disruptive and unexpected a behavior than most users want.  Even opening new windows or tabs is breaking the standard user experience, but it's a lot less unexpected than using frames.

Again, let them go.  They know where the back button is.  If you want users to come back, having content that draws them back is a lot more compelling that some gadget that lets them come back.